# Element disappear from Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash

Today, I found a really strange behavior in the Python dict object.

Here is the code:

```py
nodes = {}
for a, b in edges:
   nodes[a] = np.array([1])
   nodes[b] = np.array([1])
    
for a, b in edges:
   print(nodes[a])
   print(nodes[b])
```

Here is the error:

`print(nodes[b]) KeyError: 'https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277'`. So I guess one of the edges is not found in the dict, however all the edges have been added before in the dict.

The `edges` variable is a list of ~1500 URL string tuples (e.g. ("http://abc", "https://xyz")).

How is this error actually possible?

Comment: I guess you might construct a minimal reproducible snippet based on just the one edge, or even just the one key...

Comment: I figured out that if I print `a` and `b` before adding them to the dict, the error disappear, that's really strange. I forgot to say that the edges list is built previously using multiple threads and that threads are killed using only a return statement when reaching a threshold (maybe it is the cause).

Comment: Maybe dial the threshold right down in an effort to reduce the data needed for reproducing the issue...

Comment: Assert that all threads are dead before the above code runs. This is likely a race condition where `node` is extended between the two loops. Be sure you get a _signal_ that the thread is dead, not just a logical condition. Threads can interleave in arbitrary ways.

Comment: edit your question to reflect the threading part